# log assertion result in NoN GUI mode[Jmeter]

Tags: command-line, jmeter, jmx, assertion

How to log assertion result to a csv file in Non Gui mode
i tried command
`jmeter -n -t user.jmx -l D:/Reports/TestReport.csv -e -o D:/Reports/htmlReport/ -j Reports/jmeter.log`

Assertion result is present in my jmx file but it is not log to any file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly do you want to "log" and how?

By default JMeter logs assertion failure messages into the .jtl file, there is `failureMessage` column where all assertion failures go

Demo:

[image]

If you don't see this `failureMessage` column in the .jtl results file most probably you (or somebody else) modified default [results file configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config), in order to get the value back add the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertions=true
```

and upon JMeter restart you will start seeing assertion results in your .jtl file.

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: And how do we make devops read the file?  do we have to write the parsing ourselves?